# Mark text in Interface Builder as not needing translation

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I use dummy text in Interface Builder. Here is an example.

The `MYNAME` is not really interface text, and it is set programmatically in `viewDidLoad`. Can I mark this a special way so that it is excluded from my translations files by default?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ibtool` to set up the strings for localization/translation, you cannot exclude words directly.  Use the `--export-XLIFF` option on `ibtool` to create an XLIFF file. You then edit the excluded strings in the XLIFF file by adding the attribute `translate="no"`. The edited XLIFF file then goes to the translators who (hopefully) can use it.